# "Can't open display" when using `scp`

Tags: scp

When I type `scp file1 user@host.com:file2` into the command prompt, I get the message

```
Can't open display
Can't open display
Can't open display
Can't open display
Can't open display
file1                          100%  589KB 589.0KB/s  00:00
```

And then I wait for about 10 seconds, before the `scp` returns to the command line.  This does not happen with `ssh`, only with `scp`.  I am using Fedora 18.

Comment: Would you mind to try an absolute path, e.g.: `scp file1 user@host.com:/home/user/file2 `?

Comment: Same thing happens.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your profile scripts probably have some commands that expect an interactive session with a [terminal emulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator). And they fail when executed in a non-interactive `scp` session.

For example, if you are using bash, such commands should be moved from `.bashrc` script to `.bash_profile`.

Or use `TERM` or `PS1` environment variable or similar trick to skip those commands for a non-interactive session.

```bash
# If running interactively, then:
if [ "$PS1" ]; then

#### Alex's funky commands might go here                          <------
    /usr/bin/ssh-agent &

    # If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
    case $TERM in
    xterm*)
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
#### Alex's funky commands might also go here if they apply to xterm sessions  <------
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
    esac

fi
```

This will not evaluate if you use `scp` to copy a file, but will if you start an interactive session.

*(The sample code is by [@Criggie](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/129603/criggie))*

Comment: You are correct, it's the commands in `.bashrc` that were causing this to happen.

Comment: Would you share what those commands were, or some information about them, @Alex?

Comment: There were `xrandr` commands intended to detect which screens are present, and to arrange them in an appropriate order.

Comment: I thought `scp` used a special `sftp` subsystem rather than doing a regular SSH login.

Comment: @Barmar 1) `scp` does not use SFTP subsystem. 2) Even `sftp` would suffer the same problem - SFTP still runs over SSH login.